# Why the 'and' operator isn't working in the Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

What's supposed to be wrong in the following `if-else` statement in my template?

```
{% if rp.package.patient_type != "CASH" and rp.realization.cash == True %} N/A {% else %} {{rp.realization.deficit_or_surplus_amount}} {% endif %}
```

Even when the patient type is Cash, it displays N/A. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: If it is `Cash`, it is not `CASH`.

Comment: In my database, it is saved as CASH. All in capitals.

Comment: Just to be sure that it is `CASH` in your database, you may need to print the queryset value.

Comment: I did check and it is CASH..